# "prone to collapse" or "prone to collapsing"?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

Is there a difference between something that is "prone to **collapse**" and "prone to **collapsing**"?  The former appears to be more common than the latter - but are they both acceptable?

Comment: Both are acceptable. 'Prone to' is usually (but not exclusively) followed by a noun with/without adjective as in *'he is prone to fits of fury,'* but can also be followed by a verb. In your example, 'collapse' is a noun while 'collapsing' is a verb form of 'to collapse' that functions as a noun : such a word is called a **gerund** [Google search: 'gerund'](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=gerund&oq=gerund) Whether to use 'collapse' or 'collapsing' depends on the situation as in 'the roof is prone to *collapse* ***if*** a heavy wind blows' / 'the roof is prone to *collapsing in a heavy wind.'*

Answer (score -2):

What English Student said, but the answer is that it takes a gerund or a noun, not an infinitive. In this particular case, the infinitive also happens to be the same form as the noun. If it were about eating too much, *"prone to eating too much"* would be correct, and *"prone to eat too much"* would be incorrect.

Comment: You can check any dictionary and they will all list "prone to" + infinitive as correct though